# Click event only happened once

Tags: jquery

Click event only works the first time and not subsequent times. Here is my code:

```
<div class="image" id="image">
    <img src="blah.jpg">
    <div class="btn-edit">Edit</div>
</div>
```

I've also tried it with `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` but the bug is still there. The `console.log` statement only prints once so subsequent click events are not registered.

```
$('.btn-edit').click(function(e){
    // e.preventDefault();
    // e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('edit clicked');
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.hide();
    parent.prev().show();
});
```

On another part of the code, I have shown the image and edit button again, so the `Edit` button is visible. I'm not showing it here because it's not really relevant. You can assume the `Edit` button is visible the second time but it's not clickable.

Comment: There is nothing in the code which will prevent that. Problem is somewhere else. You must be doing something else with `'.btn-edit'`

Comment: ofcourse, you hide it after first click, so how could you click it again

Comment: [___Supporting @AmitSoni___](http://jsfiddle.net/eaB4t/)

Comment: ^^^ may not be the case there is a possibility that OP might be displaying div again somehow

Comment: @Satpal In that case, the event needs to be delegated.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I think you might be right. Are you suggesting using click events on classes is not a good practice? I've never used click events on classes and have always used a delegate, that's why I have not seen this type of error before.

Comment: @hjpotter92, I am stopping myself from posting event delegation as answer as it would be pure speculative.

Comment: I checked my code, there is only one place I used `.btn-edit` for event listening.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed this to use event delegation and it works. I guess this is why event delegation exists, so that you don't bind click events to classes! Thanks to @hjpotter92 for his suggestion!

```
$('.image').on('click', '.btn-edit', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('edit clicked');
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.hide();
    parent.prev().show();
});
```